# Compare 'YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS' format timestamps in windows jq

Tags: windows, cmd, jq

I was using `jq` on Ubuntu, but now I have to port my commands to Windows 8.1. I am using `jq` 1.6.

But I get this error while using `strptime` on Windows `jq`.

> jq: error (at xxxx.json:xxx): strptime/1 not implemented on this platform

What are the other options for `strptime` for Windows?

EXAMPLE:

This works on Ubuntu for me, and need to make it work on Windows(just need the time difference in seconds).

```
jq -n '{"t1": "2018-06-01 12:45:56", "t2": "2018-06-03 22:10:01"} |
       (.t2 | strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | mktime)-
       (.t1 | strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | mktime)'
206645
```

UPDATE:

I just found that even `mktime` generates same error for me on Windows. So I updated the question that I need just some way to compare the datetime of specific format in units of seconds(with or without using `strptime`).

Comment: Have you installed jq 1.6 on the Windows machine?  See https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation#windows-using-appveyor for details.

Comment: Yes I am using jq 1.6.

Comment: I would use jq's support for regular expressions, especially `capture`.

Comment: I don't understand what can `capture` do for me(I can not extract day of week and day of year required to pass to `mktime`), I have updated the question with more details of my requirement.

Comment: Please provide further details in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Just updated the question, with sample code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a "plug-in" implementation of jq's `mktime/0`:

```
# [1970,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0] | mktime #=> 0
# For Jan, use 0 for $m.
# Emit null if any inputs are judged to be invalid.
# No attempt to account for leap seconds is made.
# Can also be used for earlier years.
#
# Adapted from
# https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11614/determine-total-number-of-seconds-since-the-epoch
def mktime:
  def max: if .[0] > .[1] then .[0] else .[1] end;
  def min: if .[0] > .[1] then .[1] else .[0] end; 
  def NDaysInMonth: [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

  . as [$y,  $m,  $d,  $h,  $mn,  $s]
  | if ($y < 0 or $m < 0 or $d < 1 or $h < 0 or $mn < 0 or $s < 0)
    then null
    else
    1970 as $ye # UNIX epoch 01/01/1970
    | (if $y > $ye then 1 else -1 end) as $sign
    | ([$y, $ye] | max) as $maxY
    | ([$y, $ye] | min) as $minY
    | reduce range($minY; $maxY) as $i ({nleapYears: 0};
        if (($i % 100 != 0 and $i % 4 == 0) or $i % 400 == 0) then .nleapYears += 1 else . end)
    | if ($m > 1) and (($y % 100 != 0 and $y % 4 == 0) or $y % 400 == 0)
      then .nleapYears += $sign
      else .
      end
    | .nleapYears |= ([0, .] | max)
    | reduce range(0;$m) as $i (.monthsNDays = 0;
        .monthsNDays += NDaysInMonth[$i])
    | (($y - $ye) * 365 + $sign * .nleapYears + .monthsNDays + $d - 1) * 86400
        + $h * 3600 + $mn * 60 + $s
    end ;
```

Next, to parse date strings of the form `"2018-06-01 12:45:56"`, you can easily use jq's `capture` (see the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)).  Since SO is not a free programming service, this is left as an exercise, as is putting all the pieces together.

Comment: I was just checking [this](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/time/mktime.c), to make my own `mktime` function. So thanks for the answer. BTW I would remove the definitions of `max` and `min` as already available in `jq`.